# ASP.NET Dictionary get value from key inside of value inside of value

Tags: asp.net, dictionary

How I could get the value of "status" since i can only access to "operation" key and can not go further...

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4oZH.png)

Edit: i find out! thanks!

```
 var status = ((Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)statusResponse.Data["operations"])["gCxXy6aVz4sebmMyKpsT"])["status"];
```

Comment: So the value of the dictionary is `Object` but actually  a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>`

Comment: yeah, but I don't know how to obtain it.. i was looking over internet and couldn't found it. I am newbie at this language QQ

Comment: Ok, i could find out! Thanks! var status = ((Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)statusResponse.Data["operations"])["gCxXy6aVz4sebmMyKpsT"])["status"];